# The method is undefined for the type ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Я делаю интерфейс для банка, где есть администратор и клиенты, которые могут иметь разные счета в банке, снимать деньги и класть их на счет. Использую **java swing**

У меня созданы такие классы:

- `Customer`, который содержит `arraylist` из `CustomerAccounts`
- `CustomerAccount`,который является супер классом для
  `CustomerDepositAccount` и  `CusotmerCurrentAccount` и содержит
  `arraylist` из `AccountTransaction`.

И есть сам класс `AccountTransaction`.

Я запрашиваю пароль, личный код и номер аккаунта, чтобы открыть следующее окно, в котором пользователь может снять деньги.
Для этого использую следующее условие:

```
if(userName.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && 
   password.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPassword()) &&
   number.getText().equals(BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
                                        .getAccounts()
                                        .getAccountNumber()))
```

Проблема возникает здесь - `getAccountNumber()`.
И вот ошибка:

```
The method getAccountNumber() is undefined for the type ArrayList<CustomerAccount>
```

В связи с этим вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы все методы, написанные в моем классе `CustomerAccount` были видны другим классам, которые исходят из этого класса.

#### UPDATE

Это мой класс для клиента:

```
public class Customer {
    private String pps;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String birthday;
    private String password;
    private ArrayList < CustomerAccount > accounts;

    private int id;


    static AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();

    Customer() {
        id = 0;
        this.pps = "";
        this.name = "";
        this.surname = "";
        this.birthday = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.accounts = new ArrayList < CustomerAccount > ();
    }

    Customer(int id, String pps, String name, String surname, String birthday, String password) {

        this.id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
        id++;

        this.pps = pps;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.password = password;
        this.accounts = new ArrayList < CustomerAccount > ();
    }
```

Так же он содержит `setter` и `getter` методы для всех переменных.

Следующий класс это - `CustomerAccount`.
У него похожая история:

```
public class CustomerAccount implements Serializable {

    protected int accountNumber;
    protected double balance;
    public ArrayList < AccountTransaction > transactions;
    protected AccountTransaction trans;
    public CustomerAccount() {
        this.accountNumber = 0;
        this.balance = 0.0;
        this.transactions = new ArrayList < AccountTransaction > ();
    }

    public CustomerAccount(int accountNumber, double balance, AccountTransaction trans) {

        Random n = new Random();
        this.accountNumber = 100000 + n.nextInt(900000);
        this.balance = balance;
        this.transactions = new ArrayList < AccountTransaction > ();
    }
```

Это методы `set` и `get` с класса `CustomerAccount`

```
public void setAccountTransaction(ArrayList < AccountTransaction > transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
}

public ArrayList < AccountTransaction > getTransactions() {
    return this.getTransactions();
}
```

Так же существуют классы `CustomerCurrentAccount` и `CustomerDepositAccount`, в них просто добавляется по дополнительной переменной, и это не относится к сути вопроса.

Так же есть класс `AccountTransaction`, в котором есть тоже все методы, для созданных мною переменных:

```
public class AccountTransaction {

    private String date;
    private String type;
    private double amount;

    public AccountTransaction() {
        String date = "";
        String type = "";
        double amount = 0.0;
    }

    public AccountTransaction(String date, String type, double amount) {
        this.date = date;
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
```

Теперь самое главное. У меня есть класс `BankInterface`, в котором находятся все остальные диалоги, через которых я даю возможность пользователю и администратору пользоваться системой.

```
/* ArrayLists */
private ArrayList < Customer > customers = new ArrayList < Customer > ();
static Customer currentCustomer;
static CustomerAccount currentAccount;
static AccountTransaction currentTrans;

public BankInterface() {

    super("Bank Interface");
    initComponents();
}

public static void setCurrentCustomer(Customer c) {
    currentCustomer = c;
}

public static Customer getCurrentCustomer() {
    return currentCustomer;
}

public static void setCurrentAccount(CustomerAccount account) {
    currentAccount = account;
}

public CustomerAccount getCurrentAccount() {
    return currentAccount;
}
public static void setCurrentTrans(AccountTransaction trans) {
    currentTrans = trans;
}

public AccountTransaction getCurrentTrans() {
    return currentTrans;
}
```

В `initComponents` находятся все, что связано с интерфейсом.

Когда я, например, создаю аккаунты для клиента, я даю ему ввести данные:

```
/*Action Listener to create accounts */
createAc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ");
        JLabel jUserName = new JLabel("PPS Number:");
        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        JLabel jPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        Object[] ob = {
            jUserName, userName, jPassword, password
        };
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, "Please input password for JOptionPane showConfirmDialog", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        boolean found = false;
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            String userNameValue = userName.getText();
            String passwordValue = password.getText();
            for (Customer aCustomer: customers) {

                if (userName.getText().equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && password.getText().equals(aCustomer.getPassword())) {
                    BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);

                    found = true;

                    new createAccountDialog(BankInterface.this, customers);
                }
            }

            if (!found) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The PPS Number or password is not correct", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Потом, когда клиент проходит авторизацию, у него есть возможность выбрать, какой аккаунт он хочет создать - `сurrent` или `deposit` и сколько денег он хочет положить на счет.

Так я добавляю аккаунты для клиента:

```
BankInterface.setCurrentAccount(current);
BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().add(current);
```

И этот код работает для меня. `BankInterface` это драйвер класс. `set` и `get` методы для `CurrentCustomer`, у меня находятся в драйвер классе, и являются типом `static`, я показала это ранее.

Теперь же, когда я хочу добавить `transaction` к аккаунту (и сначала также хочу ввести пароль и т.д.) у пользователя есть возможность снять деньги. Я создаю для этого диалог и, таким образом, пытаюсь сохранить мои `transactions` для одного аккаунта. Поэтому, я перед этим и спросила у пользователя его `accountNumber`, чтобы знать с какого аккаунта снять деньги.

```
AccountTransaction transactions = new AccountTransaction(date, type, amount);

BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer();
int arraySize = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
                             .getAccounts().size();
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
                 .getAccounts()
                 .get(i)
                 .getTransactions()
                 .add(transactions);
```

И теперь мне стало выдавать следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at CustomerAccount.getTransactions(CustomerAccount.java:52)
```

я действительно потерялась в создании `arraylist`, которые должны переходить из одного класса в другой. Извините, если объясняю что-то непонятно.

****UPDATE 2****

```
/*Action Listener to allow customer to withdraw from deposit account */
depositW.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ");

        boolean found = false;
        boolean found1 = false;

        JLabel jUserName = new JLabel("PPS Number:");
        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        JLabel jPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        JTextField password = new JPasswordField();
        JLabel jNumber = new JLabel("Account number:");
        JTextField number = new JTextField();

        Object[] ob = {
            jUserName, userName, jPassword, password, jNumber, number
        };
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, ob, "Please input password for JOptionPane showConfirmDialog", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            String userNameValue = userName.getText();
            String passwordValue = password.getText();
            String numberValue = number.getText();

            for (Customer aCustomer: customers) {

                int arraySize = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().size();

                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

                    if (userName.getText().equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && password.getText().equals(aCustomer.getPassword())) && number.getText().equals(aCustomer.getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber()) {

                        BankInterface.setCurrentCustomer(aCustomer);
                        found = true;
                        new WithdrawDepositDialog(BankInterface.this, customers);
                    } else if (!found) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The PPS Number, password or account number is not correct", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Теперь я не могу войти в систему через этот диалог. Видимо `accountNumber` не считывается.

**UPDATE 3**
Теперь я хочу вызвать метод `withdraw` с моего класса  `AccountTransaction` . у меня есть методы с этого класса:

```
public void lodgement(double amount) {

    this.amount = this.amount + amount;
}
public void withdraw(double amount) {

    this.amount = this.amount - amount;
}
```

Могу ли я использовать set метод для этого как в следующем примере: ()
такую ошибку показывает: `The method withdraw(double) is undefined for the type new ActionListener()`

```
AccountTransaction transactions = new AccountTransaction(date, type, amount);

BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer();
int arraySize = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().size();


for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

    int arraySize1 = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getTransactions().size();
    for (int a = 0; a < arraySize1; a++) {
        BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getTransactions().add(transactions);
        BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getTransactions().get(a) withdraw(amount);

        dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Ваш метод `getAccounts()`, должно быть, возвращает `ArrayList<CustomerAccount>`. У `ArrayList<>` нет метода `getAccountNumber()`.

Comment: Как сочетаются `aCustomer` и `BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()`? Похоже, что программист, дописывая условия в `if`, забыл, с чего он начал.

Comment: LEQUADA, именно. я просто не знала пройти через это arraylist в мой класс, где есть этот метод

Comment: Igor, они сочетаются в моем driver классе, название которого BankInterface. И с ними нет проблем, так как CurrentCustomer позволяет мне открыть лист аккаунтов именно для определенного клиента, когда тот вводит пароль

Comment: @Alex - ну вот :( Давайте сначала о бизнес-логике: Вы же не хотите одну и ту же транзакцию добавить ко всем аккаунтам? Покажите код `getTransactions`. Этот метод прямо или косвенно вызывает себя же.

Comment: @Alex, всё стало очень запутанно. Где-то вы зацикливаетесь и выпадает такая ошибка. Попробуйте отредактировать вопрос. Добавьте туда свои методы. Если не полностью, то хотя бы то, что они принимают и что возвращают. На словах типа "Этот класс является суперклассом того, который в свою очередь делает то-то и так-то, который ..." всё становится ещё сложнее. Есть книга "Программист прагматик". Там описывается "Метод утёнка". Метод заключается в том, что если вы не знаете, как решить задачу, то попробуйте объяснить её игрушечному утёнку. Так вот,постарайтесь объяснить нам задачу как можно подробно

Comment: Я очень сильно извиняюсь. Сейчас все исправлю.

Comment: `getTransactions()` !!! - calls itself. `public ArrayList<AccountTransaction> getTransactions(){ return this.transactions; }`

Comment: @Igor, как мне его соединить, чтобы когда я писала эту строчку BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts(), я могла бы к ней добавить getTransactions()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вангую такое исправление:

```
int arraySize =  BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().size();

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    if(userName.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && 
       password.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPassword()) && 
       number.getText()
             .equals(BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
             .getAccounts()
             .get(i)
             .getAccountNumber())){
        ...
    }
}
```

Метод `get(i)` возвращает `i`-ый элемент `ArrayList`, которым является объект `CustomerAccount`, у которого, как я подозреваю, есть метод `getAccountNumber()`

#### UPDATE

В классе `CustomerAccount` замените `get` метод

```
public ArrayList < AccountTransaction > getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
}
```

#### UPDATE 3

У вас пробел вместо точки в строке

```
BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
             .getAccounts()
             .get(i)
             .getTransactions()
             .get(a) withdraw(amount);
```

Должно быть так

```
BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()
             .getAccounts()
             .get(i)
             .getTransactions()
             .get(a)
             .withdraw(amount);
```

#### UPDATE 4

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    System.out.println("Username: " + userName.getText() + " = " + aCustomer.getPps());
    System.out.println("Password: " + password.getText() + " = " + aCustomer.getPassword());
    System.out.println("Number: " + number.getText() + " = " +  BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber());
    if(...)
```

Comment: Вы все правильно сказали! Спасибо большое! Если я перед этим  сделаю так: int i = 0; не помешает ли это поиску чрез мой arraylist?

Comment: @Alex, если вы сделаете `i = 0`, то в условии будете рассматривать только первый элемент `ArrayList`. Если хотите рассмотреть все элементы, то запихните условие в цикл `for` и проверяйте каждый.

Comment: @Alex, я обновил ответ. Добавил цикл.

Comment: А клиентом пусть будет черепашка Мнеспешитьнекуда из книги Михаила Пляцковского "Солнышко на память".

Comment: @Igor, спасибо за книгу. Прочитаю обязательно. :) Вам цикл не понравился? )

Comment: @LEQADA - Если нет противопоказаний, я бы делал проверку username и пароля снаружи цикла, как и получение `BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts()`. Вообще, этот `BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer()` выглядит подозрительно рядом с `aCustomer`.

Comment: я пробовала писать как aCustomer, так и currentCustomer. там не оказалось никаких противоречий. у меня есть специальные методы для currentCustomer, и когда я создаю счета, например, я вызываю метод setCurrentCustomer, чтобы потом можно было посмотреть счета только для этого клиента

Comment: @Alex, посмотрите обновление  ответа

Comment: да, сейчас. попробую так же сделать в программе.

Comment: я знаю, что слишком много вопросов задаю. сейчас нет ошибки, и я никогда не могла подумать, что <this> играет такую важную роль в данном случае. но теперь когда я хочу войти в аккаунт, и набираю личный код, пароль и номер аккаунта, мне не войти, потому что номер аккаунта не считывается. if(userName.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && password.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPassword() && number.getText().equals(aCustomer.getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber()))

Comment: @Alex, вы всё делаете правильно. Как же учиться иначе?

Comment: хм, при чем здесь `this`?

Comment: @Alex, а как вы раньше считывали номер аккаунта?

Comment: и почему не считывается? Вот же вы вызываете `getAccountNumber()` в конце. Что все эти методы в результате возвращают?

Comment: @LEQADA, на самом деле я сегодня начала работать с этим вопросом. ничего не выходило целый день. я задала вопрос и проблема ушла (имеется в виду, что программа не выдала ошибки), но войти с помощью аккаунта так и не удалось. я просто пыталась зайти с помощью пароля и PPS номера

Comment: @Igor, извините. да, действительно не причем:)

Comment: @Alex Покажите метод `getAccountNumber()`

Comment: public int getAccountNumber(){
       return this.accountNumber;
   }

Comment: когда я набираю и пароль и apps номер и номер аккаунта, мгновенно все переходит на это - JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The PPS Number, password or account number is not correct", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); посоклько ранее все было хорошо, я сделала вывод что, что проблема именно в номере аккаунта

Comment: @Alex, а что вообще возвращает эта строка `aCustomer.getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber()`?

Comment: поскольку `aCustomer.getAccounts().getAccountNumber()` не работала и говорила что не соединения, это была моя проблема в самом начале, когда я задавала вопрос, я изменила это на `aCustomer.getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber()`

Comment: @Alex, что эта строка возвращает? Выведите на экран и посмотрите, считывает ли это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Очень странно для меня, но когда я вывела на экран с помощью этого `System.out.println(BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber());`, показало правильно все в итоге. интересно, почему же тогда не дает зайти

Comment: @Alex, возможно, какое-то условие не выполняется. Выведите все: это `aCustomer.getPps()`, это `aCustomer.getPassword()` и номер аккаунта. Они одновременно должны принимать те значения, которые вы вводили.

Comment: Не могу поверить, все работает.

Comment: @Alex, если ответ вам помог, то нажмите, пожалуйста на галочку слева от ответа. А если очень помог, то и на стрелку вверх можете нажать :)

Comment: Очень сильно помог, я никогда практически не пользовалась этим сайтом, поэтому не знала куда нажать.:) а не могли бы вы еще глянуть на мой третий update в вопросе. если конечно такое возможно.

Comment: @Alex, обновил ответ.

Comment: @LEQADA - я снимаю перед Вами шляпу.

Comment: @Igor, благодарю *краснеет

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, никогда не думала, что могут так помогать и все объяснять! Единственное, мне кажется, что я неправильно тестировала, и все же не работает `getAccountNumber`. и мне кажется, что проблема в том, что `number` это `String`, а метод у меня `int`. может быть мне стоит каким-то образом перевести int в `string`. я попробую еще покататься в этом. если получится, обязательно напишу!

Comment: @Alex, пожалуйста. Так можно перевести `int` в `String`: `Integer.toString(number)`.

Comment: Это же надо делать в том месте, где я спрашиваю пароль? или в классе, где находится эта переменная?

Comment: @Alex, можно и так, и так. Делайте там, где это исправит ситуацию. Зависит от проблемы. Вам нужно выводить на экран значения там, где подозреваете неправильное поведение.

Comment: ` int accountNumber = BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber();
         Integer.toString(accountNumber);` вот что я сделала. и может быть я была не права, может быть проблема вовсе не в этом... но когда я убирают с if statement мое последнее выражение, где number равен getAccountNumber(), тогда на экране все правильно выводится. значит дело в том, как все accountNumber считывается с моего if statement. Простите, что я вас так запутала...

Comment: @Alex, я добавил 3 вывода на экран в ответ (смотрите UPDATE 4). Они должны стоять ровно после цикла перед условием `if`. Запустите программу и введите данные с клавиатуры. А потом покажите мне точно то, что вывелось в консоль. Но я хочу, чтобы вы абсолютно точно всё показали, без ручных манипуляций.

Comment: @Alex, результат можете прямо в свой ответ добавить. Но напишите тут, чтобы я посмотрел.

Comment: @LEQADA, все вроде правильно. Username: 1234567 = 1234567
Password: 1234567 = 1234567
Number: 759657  = 759657  Только эти строчки появлялись в консоле без остановки.

Comment: @Alex, а у вас там случайно нет блока `try-catch` в методе с `if`? Может вы туда попадаете? Поставьте какой-нибудь вывод на экран в блоке `catch`, если он есть.

Comment: нет, вообще в этой программе не использовала try - catch

Comment: @Alex, покажите, пожалуйста, последний вариант вашего `if`.

Comment: `if (!found){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The PPS Number, password or account number is not correct", "Please try again", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
              }  `вы имеете в виду этот вариант? если да, то он есть у меня в вопросе наверху.

Comment: @Alex, не я про тот `if`, который внутри цикла. Тот, который не срабатывает у вас.

Comment: `if(userName.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && password.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPassword())){` сейчас он простой, иначе ничего не открывается

Comment: @Alex, ну верните туда проверку аккаунта. Я пытаюсь понять в чём проблема. Или вы уже решили всё?

Comment: Вернула, происходит тоже самое.Username: 1234567 = 1234567 Password: 1234567 = 1234567 Number: 759657 = 759657 Только эти строчки появлялись в консоле без остановки.

Comment: @Alex, покажите мне сам if, не вывод. Я хочу код посмотреть.

Comment: `for(int w = 0; i < arraySize; w++){
       System.out.println("Username: " + userName.getText() + " = " + aCustomer.getPps());
       System.out.println("Password: " + password.getText() + " = " + aCustomer.getPassword());
       System.out.println("Number: " + number.getText() + " = " +  BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber());
   }
  if(userName.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPps()) && password.getText( ).equals(aCustomer.getPassword()) && number.getText().equals(BankInterface.getCurrentCustomer().getAccounts().get(i).getAccountNumber())){`

Comment: @Alex, У ВАС `IF` ВНЕ ЦИКЛА `FOR`!!!111!

Comment: я поместила его в цикл. как только я нажимаю на окей, появляется окно, с надписью, что неверный логин, пароль или номер аккаунта. и в консоле `Username: 1234567 = 1234567
Password: 1234567 = 1234567
Number: 775877 = 775877` это появляется один раз теперь .

Comment: @Alex, вы понимаете для чего вам там нужен цикл? Этот код вообще вы писали? Вы знаете, что такое цикл? Индекс в цикле вы используете внутри `if`. А значит ваш `if` должен быть ВНУТРИ цикла `for`, а не за его фигурными скобками.

Comment: @Alex, а выводы на экран (посмотрите внимательно мой ответ) должны быть между циклом `for` и `if`. То есть внутри `for`, но вне `if`. Тогда выводиться будет столько раз, сколько у вас элементов в `ArrayList`. А если не выходит столько раз, значит у вас внутри `if` происходит то, что портит всю картину. Для того, чтобы убедиться в этом, достаточно поставить один вывод на экран первой строкой в блоке `if`. Вы увидите, что условие срабатывает, а дальше какая-то проблема.

Comment: В том, что вы мне уже показали, все замечания я уже сделал. Если вы будете внимательны ко всем словам из моих комментариев, то для того, чтобы исправить проблему вам нужно будет только запастись терпением и на каждом шагу выводить на экран ожидаемые результаты переменных. Лишь тогда вы поймёте, где ошибка и как её устранить. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли! Буду стараться.